# Postfix Blocking E-mail from address containing two @ symbols

Tags: regex, email, postfix-mta, sender

My mail server has been receiving a lot of spam with malicious links and attachments lately which have "From" addresses that contain a valid address from my domain with an additional @someotherdomain.hn address appended.

For example:
John Smith has an e-mail address of JohnSmith@mydomain.com
I receive e-mail with a "from" address of JohnSmith@mydomain.com@someotherdomain.hn

I would like to know if it is possible to block e-mail if the "from" address contains more than one "@" symbol.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux servers. [sf] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tag as `Regex` so I assume you want a regex that matches addresses with 2 '`@`' symbols.

Here it is:

```
/@.*@/
```

This will match any address with 2 (or more) `@`-signs.

It simply starts with matching '`@`', followed by zero or more characters, and finally another '`@`'.

All you have to do is delete the mail, if there's a match.

`Edit`:

To only match when one mail address has two '`@`' signs, and not when there are two addresses (each with a single @), you can use this Regex (assuming addresses are separated by comma '`,`'):

```
/@[^,]*@/
```

Again, if there's a match, delete it.

Comment: Or `/@.*@/` if you also want to block addresses with two consecutive `@` characters. It's a bit simpler, and since it doesn't use `+` it's valid both as an extended regular expression and as a basic regular expression. (Note that the `/` characters are not part of the regex; they may or may not be required by whatever tool us using the regex.)

Comment: I have also received that kind of mail. They always contain a valid email domain between the @s. The domain is of course meant to fool you.

Comment: Sure, but using `/@.*@/` is simpler, it covers all the cases you're concerned about *plus* two consecutive `@` characters, and it's more portable to different regex implementations.

Comment: @Keith To please you :-)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately, this also appears to block messages that have two destination e-mail addresses so I will need to do some more research.

Comment: How are two destinations separated? With a comma?